# Split commas separeted cell in pandas dataframe into different columns

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

How do I split the comma-separated string to new columns

Expected output

```
    Source       Target      Weight
0  Majed Moqed  Majed Moqed      0
```

Comment: First `#Get each element into its column by spliting the existing single column` as follows
`s=df['(Source,Target,Weight)'].str.split('\,', expand=True)` then
`#Set columns` as follows
`s.columns=list(df.columns.str.replace('[^A-Za-z\,]','', regex=True).str.split(','))[0]`
print(s)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Source'] = df['(Source, Target, Weight)'].split(',')[0]
df['Target'] = df['(Source, Target, Weight)'].split(',')[1]
df['Weight'] = df['(Source, Target, Weight)'].split(',')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
col = '(Source, Target, Weight)'
df = pd.DataFrame(df[col].str.split(',').tolist(), columns=col[1:-1].split(', '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
col = '(Source, Target, Weight)'
df[col.strip('()').split(', ')] = df[col].str.split(',', expand=True)
```